# How to call function from where-object

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

When I'm executing the script nothing is logging into `Test.json`.

Can any one tell me how to call function from `where-object` in inline query?

```
function getDateOfTimeStamp($dateString) {
    [string[]] $format = @("MM/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", "M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")
    $result = $null
    $format.ForEach( { [DateTime] $dt = New-Object DateTime; if ([datetime]::TryParseExact($dateString, $_, [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture, [System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles]::None, [ref] $dt)) { $result = $dt } })
    $result
}
$storageaccount = Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -StorageAccountName test123 -ResourceGroupName testinggroup
$table = Get-AzureStorageTable -Name testtable123
$query = New-Object Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableQuery
$data = $table.CloudTable.ExecuteQuery($query)       
$data | % { EntityToObject $_ } | Select-Object PartitionKey, RowKey, DateModified| Where-Object {getDateOfTimeStamp DateModified -lt ((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().AddDays(-10))} | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File "C:\\Test.json"
```

Comment: `getDateOfTimeStamp DateModified` -> `(getDateOfTimeStamp $_.DateModified)`

Comment: How can we delete the rows based on above condtions from table.

Comment: @sandeep Hi, my answer work for you? Please let me know if you need more future help.

Answer (score 0):

As Mathias R. Jessen said, you need modify `getDateOfTimeStamp DateModified` to `getDateOfTimeStamp $_.DateModified`

> How can we delete the rows based on above condtions from table.

You could use `Remove-AzureStorageTableRow` to delete the rows that selected.

On your scenario, you could try below:

```
$removedata=$data | % { EntityToObject $_ } | Select-Object PartitionKey, RowKey, DateModified| Where-Object {getDateOfTimeStamp DateModified -lt ((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().AddDays(-10))}
$removedata|Remove-AzureStorageTableRow -table $table
```

I like following script to delete 10 days before rows in a table.

```
$rgname=""
$storagename=""
$tablename=""
$saContext = (Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -StorageAccountName $storagename -ResourceGroupName $rgname).Context
$table = Get-AzureStorageTable -Name $tablename -Context $saContext
$query = New-Object Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableQuery
$data = $table.CloudTable.ExecuteQuery($query)    
$remove=$data  | Select-Object PartitionKey, RowKey, TimeStamp| Where-Object {$_.TimeStamp -lt ((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().AddDays(-10))} 
$removedata|Remove-AzureStorageTableRow -table $table
```

More information about this please refer to this blog:[Working with Azure Storage Tables from PowerShell](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/paulomarques/2017/01/17/working-with-azure-storage-tables-from-powershell/).

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.